# Плохой Javascript код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Выполнял тестовое задание.

**Из комментариев:**

> Надо сделать игру. Поле 4х4 квадратика. У квадратов состояние по
>   умолчанию "закрыто". Клик по квадрату переключает состояние на
>   "открыто". Надо открыть 2 квадрата. Каждый второй квадрат одинакового
>   цвета. Нажал на два квадрата одинакового цвета, они переходят в
>   "открытое" состояние. Если с разным цветом, то обратно в "закрытое".
>   Надо открыть все квадраты.

Вот моя попытка:

```
var square0 = document.getElementById("0");
var square1 = document.getElementById("1");
var square2 = document.getElementById("2");
var square3 = document.getElementById("3");
var square4 = document.getElementById("4");
var square5 = document.getElementById("5");
var square6 = document.getElementById("6");
var square7 = document.getElementById("7");
var square8 = document.getElementById("8");
var square9 = document.getElementById("9");
var square10 = document.getElementById("10");
var square11 = document.getElementById("11");
var square12 = document.getElementById("12");
var square13 = document.getElementById("13");
var square14 = document.getElementById("14");
var square15 = document.getElementById("15");
var img0 = document.getElementById("img0");
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
var img3 = document.getElementById("img3");
var img4 = document.getElementById("img4");
var img5 = document.getElementById("img5");
var img6 = document.getElementById("img6");
var img7 = document.getElementById("img7");
var img8 = document.getElementById("img8");
var img9 = document.getElementById("img9");
var img10 = document.getElementById("img10");
var img11 = document.getElementById("img11");
var img12 = document.getElementById("img12");
var img13 = document.getElementById("img13");
var img14 = document.getElementById("img14");
var img15 = document.getElementById("img15");
var count = 0;
var arr = [];
```

Проверяющим не понравился этот код. Сказали, так точно не надо делать.

Как можно сделать иначе? Нужно получить доступ к элементам `<div>` и `<img>`.

Comment: Изложите суть задания, которое вы решали. Пока ваш вопрос бессмысленен с точки зрения инспекции кода.

Comment: Как сделать лучше етот код?

Comment: Повторяю, изложите суть стоявшей перед вами задачи. Без этого вопрос бессмысленен.

Comment: "Так точно не стоит делать.

И в целом по коду все в таком же стиле."
                      Как ето понять?От такой был ответ.В каком ето стиле?Как надо сделать?

Comment: **Задачи**, а не ответа на ваше решение.

Comment: Надо сделать игру.
поле 4х4 квадратика
клик по квадрату состояние "открыто"

Comment: Вам поставили задачу: "Сделайте игру!"? Или какая-то другая формулировка была, что вы написали такой код?

Comment: Круто! А как играть в то, что вы написали?

Comment: Надо сделать игру.
поле 4х4 квадратика
дефалтное состояние "закрыто"
клик по квадрату состояние "открыто"
надо открыть 2 квадрата
каждый второй квадрат одиноковый цвет
нажал на два квадрата одинакового цвета они переходят в "открытое" состояние
если с разным цветом то обратно в "закрытое"
надо открыть все квадраты

Comment: @RomanPawliw вы сейчас это какому переводчику пишите? Я б за такие формулировки мыслей ссылал бы в тундру

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я так понял, речь об игре "Найди пару".

Answer (score 6):

Заметка: атрибут `id` элемента может начинаться с цифры, но в целях отчетливости лучше использовать что то вроде `"square" + цифра` для `id`.

Можно все сначала в словарь положить (`squares` и `images`)

```
var squares = {};
var numOfSquares = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < numOfSquares; i++) {
    squares["square" + i.toString()] = document.getElementById("square" + i.toString());
}

var images = {};
var numOfImages = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < numOfSquares; i++) {
    images["img" + i.toString()] = document.getElementById("img" + i.toString());
}
```

Затем, следующим образом можно получать и использовать элементы (пример: `square1` и `img6`)

```
var square1 = squares["square1"];
var img6 = images["img6"];
```

Comment: Укажите в своем ответе, что атрибут `id` элемента не может начинаться с цифры.

Comment: @VenZell, устаревшее требование: [Previous versions of HTML placed greater restrictions on the content of ID values (for example, they did not permit ID values to begin with a number).](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: @Grundy, фига се, не знал. Спасибо.

Comment: @VenZell, честно говоря я тоже не знал :-) хотел слова ссылкой подкрепить, глянул что ссылка на 4 стандарт, поискал новый и вот :)

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, будет лучше не зацикливать getElementById, а воспользоваться [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

```
var squares = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

Comment: Плохая идея, можно лишнего выбрать. Надо хотя бы селектор по классу или роли добавить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, либо в контейнере искать, а не во всем документе

Comment: @Grundy , @PavelMayorov я не предложил готовое решение, а лишь показал более удобный путь (без циклов), ведь, вы же не будете отрицать, что `querySelectorAll` лучше чем `for` + `getElement(s)By*`

Comment: @Артём, лучше по какому критерию? :-)

Comment: @Grundy (1) отсутствие цикла, (2) часть работы с коллекцией/массивом переходит на плечи нативной функции

Comment: @Артём, при использовании `getElement(s)By*` цикл так же отсутствует. Возвращаемая коллекция ни в том, ни в другом случае не является массивом

Comment: @Grundy ну, да. Что касается `getElementsByClassName` и `getElementsByTagName` - там почти то же самое. Но `querySelector(All)` более гибкий. А на счёт того, что оная возвращает - массив не всегда нужен, ибо обратиться к нужному элементу коллекции можно как к элементу массива. А на случай перебора есть `forEach`.

Comment: @Артём, который, как выяснилось в соседнем вопросе - работает только в хроме на честном слове, это я про `forEach`

Comment: @Grundy не задавался этим вопросом. В любом случае всегда можно сделать что то наподобие `Array.prototype.*.call(nodeList)`